# Laravel: How to generate QR code merged with an image using Simple QrCode

Tags: laravel

I am trying to generate a QR code merged with an image in my Laravel project using a plugin called [Simple QrCode](https://www.simplesoftware.io/#/docs/simple-qrcode). I was able to generate a ordinary QR code, but when I try to generate one with an image merged, Instead of a QR code I get this.
[image: qrcode]

This is my code.

```
{!! QrCode::format('png')->size(200)->merge('/public/storage/home/abc_main_logo.png')->generate(url('/menu/'.Auth::user()->id)) !!}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? If there's another way to generate QR code merged with image, that would also be helpful.

Any help would be appreciated as I have tried multiple methods with no success.

Thank you in advance.

My Laravel version is 7.15.0.

Comment: `url('/menu/'.Auth::user()->id)` something wrong here. Shouldn't you pass a string here?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this code directly: {!! QrCode::format('png') ...

I used the following code:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{!! base64_encode(QrCode::format('png')...) !!}">
```